# GWT RemoteServiceServlet Request Lagging; No Response

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets, gxt

I developer a simple Form that loads Data from via RPC from an Tomcat
Server.
But sometime the request load and load and get no response from the
server. Seems to be a bug?
The server is still alive and after refreshing the site, the request
ist ok...

I think that could be a critical bug...

Simple RPC that implements my Service..

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/engine/myService

I checked the problem under GWT 2.3 and GWT 2.4. Same problem... I started after 3-4 requests.

In the Serverlogs

logger.debug("Lade Nennweite"); // IS printed in the ServerLogs
logger.debug("Test"); // NOT printed in the Serverlogs

Seems to be hanging after the Logger; I kicked the Logger but no changes...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I checked it with Tomcat 6.0.33 and Tomcat 7.0.21 no changes. 
Currently I have no idear what to do...

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {
@Override
public Map<String, ArrayList<CommonVO>> getData() {
...
}
}
```

Looks like a simple RPC Call...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I didn't close the DB Conneciton. So after 3-4 Requests all DB Connections are in used and the server is waiting to get a free connection....

Stupid error...

Comment: Remember this next time you think there is a critical bug in a framework.